# Joomla modified user system for approvals after payment & manual user checks?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I have a client who wants a paid member site. It's a big network of companies. If a company wants to become a member then they can apply online. If my client likes them after their manual inspections & field visits of said company, they can approve it for online payment and after the payment the company becomes a member or of-course they can just disapprove it.

- Every member gets one page
- Every member can edit their own information anytime and only their
  own information

Basically what I need is a user system that allows for approvals. If I separate the payment.

Apart from this, the site will have a pictures module, youtube videos module and a blog module, all for the network not any members.

In Joomla is it possible to make the above process? Is there any other PHP CMS that would do this more easily?

Links to nice Joomla Tuts or Extensions would also be really helpful.

Thanks! I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically do whatever you want in most of the cms available (joomla , wordpress , drupal , etc...)

what you will not find usually is a complete solution , you need to roll up your sleeves and start programming

links to joomla tutorials won't help you except if you don't know the difference between a module , plugin and a component .

if you know enough about php it will be easy to understand the framework of joomla and start doing ur own joomla component.

good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your response. For me programming is not the problem. I just needed to know if what I need is in fact doable. For eg: I'm a comfortable WordPress programmer and I know for a fact WordPress cannot do what I need. I've read enough to know the difference between plugin, module and component. I'm not looking for a out of the box solution, I know I will have to code my own component. I just need to know if the underlying J framework (is it?) flexible enough to do what I need.

Comment: yes it is more than flexible ... where i work it's the only cms we use and we did more than 300 sites with different solutions and it has always did the job ... Now we have our own framework built on top of joomla ... btw why you can't accomplish what you want to do in wordpress?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will start reading up. WordPress will not be the most elegant system. Maybe with some ACL plugin over the buddypress system might work but it won't be the best solution possible. How would you suggest I do it in WordPress, maybe I'll just do that. I'm much more comfortable with WordPress. If not, then any reads you suggest for learning the Joomla Framework and component building. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use xipt profile types kind of component if it awailable in 1.7 
and joomla provides a rich user management by default. there are also components such as rsmembership  which allow members to pay online to become members.hope this helps you .

good luck